# set session array and get the values in other pages without using database in php

Tags: php, arrays, session

i have some fields like where i will give input and get these data through $_POST methods and i want to use SESSION array and i want to use them in another page..how can i set the session array in one page and get the values of the array which i gave input into another page??? can anyone help me with an example or something??

for example if i want to make a page for registration where there will be three fields like name,email,password. how can i set these in session array and get these values in other page..thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your first page
main.php

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" >
<input type="text" name="field1" >
<input type="text" name="field2" >
<input type="text" name="field3" >
</form>
```

process.php

```
 <?php   session_start();
$_SESSION['field']=[]; //for old php version use $_SESSION['field']=array();
$_SESSION['field']=$_POST;
//other codes
?>
```

In your third page: lets call it take.php

```
<?php  session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['field']); //show what is in your session $_SESSION['field']['field1'], $_SESSION['field']['field1'], $_SESSION['field']['field1']
echo $_SESSION['field']['field1']; //to manipulate in session one variale after another
?>
```

this will do your trick

Comment: thnx man..it did work :) but lastly can u help me with this?? i will give multiple inputs for example first i give input as name1,mail1,pass1....secondly i give name2,mail2,pass2 and i want to show them both...at a same time....how can i do that? again thnx @fas M

Comment: You just do same trick, if name1,mail1,pass1 are for form 1 then just create its session variable and do it for name2,mail2,pass2 of form 2.  Also just mark the answer **stop saying thanks** since is not allowed to this site pal

Comment: sorry mate :P would u help me with thee code..i tried but couldn't  @fas M

Comment: So what exactly you want me to show you, two forms as i described above or what do you really want?, details plz..

Comment: it's like facebook...u registered...i registered...and keep both our info in session array..and show them..no matter what the number of sign up is..3,4 or more can register while the session exists and i want to print all of them at same time @fas M

Comment: Facebook server store only 1 form for each/everything we did worldwide, if about login, then we all share the same login page, the issue is, session variables are from server but they are stored to client, i mean browser. so just one session variable like we did above and all user who enter they are information will share the variable but with individual stored data.

Comment: yeah and i want to print these individual data of people who are registered at the current session at the same time

Comment: this data will be printed to client since server has got only 1 variable, may be you as an administrator you need to have a database table that will have two column 1 is id and second is loginStatus,, if user login, just set status to online if logged out set status to offline, then you can easily get all user who are online(number of user online) also you can print all users offline too bro. this is chat now bro that is not allowed here too

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You need to start the session on every page, (before any output!) with `session_start();`

In the `index.php`, first there are no form submitted, so it's shows the form.
Type something in the field. Submit. When you submit, `$_POST["submit"]` will exists. Store the value of your text field into a `$_SESSION` variable, and redirect the user to `other.php`. In that file, you can access your variable with key what you set in `index.php`.

```
index.php
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $_SESSION["user"] = array(
        "name" => $_POST["name"],
        "email" => $_POST["email"],
        "password" => $_POST["password"]
    );
    header("Location: other.php");
    die();
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
    Name <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    Email <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    Password <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

other.php

<?php
echo "Name is " . $_SESSION["user"]["name"] . "<br />\n";
echo "Email is " . $_SESSION["user"]["email"] . "<br />\n";
echo "Password is " . $_SESSION["user"]["password"] . "<br />\n";
```

Comment: i know this format but don't know the array format of session... @lolka_bolka

Comment: this is helpful but the inputs i will give it will show for the first one....what if i want to show multiple outputs at the same time?? thnx for ur code though :) @lolka_bolka

Answer (score 0):

just use session_start(); at each page you want to use the array. and you will be able to use it
this page will help http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

To set them:

```
<?php 
// form_submit.php
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

To retrieve them use the same value:

```
<?php
// display_name.php
$name = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['name']));
echo $name;
```

I do not recommend storing the password in your session though. While session should be secure it should never be necessary there. And sessions are stored in files so it give a potential hacker the ability to retrieve it from one more location.

This store the session in a file in a special directory by default with a fresh php install.

You will need to either use `session_start()` on the front of each page using the session variable or set session to auto start in php.ini.

Comment: Why do you create a `$name` variable, if it already in the `$_SESSION["name"]` what you can access directly?

Comment: Just an example. The point is the name is accessible through that syntax.

Comment: actually i want these name,email,password in session array and get these in another page

Comment: then please edit it for `echo $_SESSION["name"]`. I ask you this, because I am always seeing the noobs, that they create hundreds of variables from `$_POST` or `$_SESSION`, what they do not want to manipulate or use later, what is totally unnecessary. Thank you.

Comment: I would never echo a post value directly from a session. That would allow cross site scripting. Anyway I like my answer how it is. Thanks you.

Comment: @user3342503 this example is two separate pages/files. I'm assuming session auto start is set. IF it is not just put session start on the top of each.